# Vectors spaces: $V=U+W$. Technique for showing that an element belongs to $U$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be finite-dimensional vector space and let $U$, $W$ be subspaces of $V$.

Suppose that $V=U+W$.

Is there a standard argument for showing that an element belongs to $U$?

For example, if the sum was direct, if would suffice to show that a vector is not $0$ and is not in $W$ to conclude such a thing.

This may be a broad question. If there isn't such a thing, feel free to say there isn't one.

Thanks.

Comment: Let $u \in U \setminus 0$ and $w \in W \setminus 0$, and assume you have a direct sum. Then $u+w \in U \oplus W$ is not zero, it is not in $W$, but it is not in $U$ either...

Comment: You are correct. For some reason I'm thinking about these sums as unions..

Answer (score 0):

We can always show $0_V\in U$. But for non-null elements it's not true. Take $U=\{0_V\},W=V$.